# Unable to format RAW SD card?

Tags: sd-card

The phone is suddenly switched off when I copying files to my Micro SD. After that my phone couldn't detect that SD. Then I insert it to pc using card reader. when I try to open SD drive on pc, the sd card suddenly unplugged. It's happening many times. then I tried to format it when it's detected. But it's getting much time and finally it says windows is unable to format. Please anyone tell me a way to format it.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a hardware issue to me, most likely. You can try wiping the card with software, but there's no guarantees and **this will wipe all data on the card if it succeeds**. If you want to give it a shot, try the following:

1. Start with the SD card not connected to the computer.
2. Open an Administrator command prompt. Use it for the following commands.
3. Open the `diskpart` tool in CMD.
4. Make sure Windows doesn't try to automatically mount the SD card when you plug it in. First, run `automount scrub`, then `automount disable`.
5. Insert the SD card into a reader. Windows should seemingly ignore it.
6. Use the `list disk` command to find your SD card, and `select disk <#>` to select it. If you can't find it, run `rescan` and then try again.
7. Run the `clean` command to wipe any partition data on the disk already, as (if it's a data issue, rather than a hardware one) that's the most likely place that problem could cause symptoms like you describe. This command does not, so far as I know, require reading the disk metadata, though I may be wrong. If a normal `clean` doesn't work, try `clean all`; this zeroes the entire disk (or SD card), taking much longer but being much more of a sure thing.
8. Use the `create partition primary` command to create a new partition filling the SD card. This partition should by automatically selected, but you can use `list partition` / `select partition 1` to make sure.
9. Format the new partition. Run `help format` for info about formatting options, but by default a simple `format quick` should be sufficient (will use FAT32 or exFAT depending on size, I believe).
10. Use the `assign` command to give the newly-formatted SD card a drive letter. Hopefully at this point Windows doesn't freak out.
11. Restore volume auto-mounting (unless you want to leave it off) via `automount enable`.
12. Quit back to CMD using the `exit` command.
13. Go to the newly-assigned drive letter and see if you can use it.

Hope that works for you! You should be able to put the card back in the phone **(after using Eject or Safely Remove Hardware in Windows!)** and it should hopefully work.

Bear in mind, though, that if it's a hardware issues then at best you'll only put the problem off for a little while, and risk losing more time and data in the future. SD cards are relatively inexpensive but don't last forever; maybe you got a bad one that died early.

Comment: Thanks all of you....CBHAcking I tried using diskpart cmd but its saying "Diskpart has encountered an error : The semaphore timeout period has expired". Can I know the meaning of that?

Comment: @dharsh What step in the process did that happen at? In any case, though, it basically means that there was a timeout on how long the program was allowed to wait for something, and that timeout was exceeded. A "semaphore", in computer science, is a type of synchronization structure; you use it when two different bits of code want to access a shared resource and there's a limit on how many times it can be accessed in parallel. The error you got suggests that something didn't release the semaphore as quickly as it should, suggesting something is hanging instead of finishing its work.

Comment: When I entered CLEAN command, after few minutes it happend.

Comment: Sir is my sd card damaged?

Comment: As I said at the start of the answer, it sounds like a hardware issue. I'm sorry, but I suspect your SD card is likely to be damaged, yeah.

Comment: ok sir. Thanks for valuable help. have a nice day sir.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows this sbould be doable using the partitionmanagement (just search for it in start(menu)).
Be sure to select the correct, removable, device.

Generally in Windows if you face errors, a look into the eventmanager is a good thing to do.
Event Manager -> Custom Views -> Administrative Events
should have some more detailed info on whag exactly failed.

If Windows doesn't "like" the card (anymore) you should be able to confirm whether it's really broken or not with attaching it to a Linux machine and watching the `dmesg` log while doing so.
Usually it will just work fine and you can unmount the SD (if auto-mounted) and format it. Also zeroing the drive before might help:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXy
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdXy
```

be sure to replace `sdXy` with the correct device - you can also wrongly format an important drive!
You can get an overview over devices using `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0):

Once SD card can't be formatted by Windows, you should backup data first. if the drive can't be opened, you can use data recovery software to retrieve data. then you can throw this damaged SD card and buy a new one.