# DiskPart I/O device error

Tags: sd-card

[Unable to format RAW SD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/972646/unable-to-format-raw-sd-card)

I have tried over a dozen apps and I can't recover my 128GB SD card currently being used on my phone.

I get up to creating partition and I encounter the error:

> DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed
>   because of an I/O device error.

The Event Log Reads:

> The driver detected a controller error on device

This is where I'm stuck - I cant write 0's to disk... Can anyone provide any insight to what may be causing this error?

Comment: It sounds like your SD card is dead. Buy another one.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Recover data? Or just make it work again?

Comment: recover!!! i have my pics of the card. i need them. how can i go around the bad sectors and get to the raw data? windows cant work w. raw fs. cant convert bc of i/o error.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Event Log have any other details in it? An I/O device error is pretty broad. Could you also post your Phone Make/Model?

I would recommend trying out the SD card on another reader (either a PC or another phone that can support 128GB) To try and isolate the problem to the card or your phone.

From there, it's easier to troubleshoot problems on your device knowing that the SD card is working.

Comment: this is the error: The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk2\DR11.System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Disk 
   - EventID 11 
   [ Qualifiers]  49156 
    Level 2 
    Task 0 
    Keywords 0x80000000000000 
   - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2016-09-01T16:05:57.118580200Z 
    EventRecordID 231095 
    Channel System 
    Computer ****
    Security 
 - EventData 
   \Device\Harddisk2\DR11

Comment: its not the phone. its the card. the phone also barfs at me when trying to format (as an unsupported drive) the MBR and the DBR are both crap. AOMEI tried to rebuild MBR, but nothing...still cant format and create partition. doing LLF now. will see what happens after.

Answer (score -1):

that is not possible. i am sorry to tell you but your SD card is corrupted and can't be used anymore.
but if somehow you get the solution , then please inform me. i have more than 10 such useless SD cards